# Finding a total count in Impala SQL statement

Tags: sql, impala

I am trying to find a total count of all the users who have viewed a particular object in my particular table.  I have a query which, so far, breaks it apart by object...

`select object, count(distinct user) 'c' from events e where (action = 'viewed') and object in ('car','truck') group by object, 'c'`

The output looks like the following...

`car    92`

`truck  20`

What I would like is to simply output the number `112`.  Any help would be great.

Comment: What is the result of `select count(distinct user) 'c' from events e where (action = 'viewed') and object in ('car','truck')`?

Comment: @jnbbender   What is the total supposed to represent? Maybe `108` is the right answer.

Comment: No...I know `92` and `20` are correct and I simply wanted their total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `sum()` around your current query

```
select sum(c)
from
(
    select object, count(distinct user) 'c' 
    from events e 
    where (action = 'viewed') and object in ('car','truck') 
    group by object, 'c'
) tmp
```

Comment: This one is good. Ugly but good.  I never mentioned in the question but the query is built from a custom Builder object, so this solution will save me big time from any re-writes.

Answer (score 0):

Just make it simpler to get what you want:

```
select count(*) 
from events e 
where action = 'viewed' 
and object in ('car','truck')
```

if you want distinct users by object you can do this

```
select count(*) 
from events e 
where action = 'viewed' 
  and object in ('car','truck') 
  and ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Object, User) = 1
```

Comment: The problem here is `distinct`.  The answer from this query came back `151`

Comment: @jnbbender ok you can do that with a windowing function in the where clause as I show above.